# Blazor not building dist bundle

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When i try to use `dotnet publish` on Windows to build my Blazor App, I get a folder structure that looks like the following:

```
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.json
PersonalWebsite.deps.json
PersonalWebsite.dll
PersonalWebsite.exe
PersonalWebsite.pdb
PersonalWebsite.runtimeconfig.json
PersonalWebsite.Views.dll
PersonalWebsite.Views.pdb
web.config
wwwroot
```

but I don't get a dist bundle that I could deploy to, for example, Github Pages.
Anyone know how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dist bundle is deprecated.